# Writing partitioned dataset to HDFS/S3 with _SUCCESS file in each partition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

when writing a partitioned dataset to HDFS/S3, a _SUCCESS file is written to the output directory upon successful completion. I'm curious if there is way to get a _SUCCESS file written to each partitioned directory ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww It is a perfectly valid question and definitely not something that could be answered on Super User or Unix. Context might not be obvious without the context, but it clear if you consider the tags.

Comment: @femibyte Why would you need that? `_SUCCESS` marks completion of the job and no partition can be considered completed, until a whole job is. Is there any particular use case here?

Comment: I want to be able to use the _SUCCESS flag as an indicator in a luigi workflow where the pipeline writes to a new daily s3 partition. Because the location is partitioned, the _SUCCESS flag is created at the "folder" above rather than the newly created partitioned directory itself.

Comment: I'm facing this problem for a daily ETL. I need to to be able to keep a record of what ETLs succeeded, even while multiple ETLs may run at the same time or out of chronological order. Would love to see an elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

For the time being, you may be able to get your desired result by writing out files directly to `path/to/table/partition_key1=foo/partition_key2=bar` and not using the Parquet writer's `partitionBy` argument.

FWIW, I also believe that `_SUCCESS` files should be written out to every partition, especially given that [SPARK-13207](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13207) and [SPARK-20236](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20236) have been resolved.

Comment: I've filed a [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26052) for this.

Comment: Was this resolved? I am still seeing _SUCESS file being written in the outermost folder and not in each partition.

Comment: How can I write it this way - path/to/table/partition_key1=foo/partition_key2=bar when the dataframe can have different rows with different values for the partition keys (foo & bar are not fixed)?

Comment: @MK22, you will not be able to write it in a single call. You will have to break up the dataframe by keys and then write them individually to their destination partitions.