# Is there a way to do write in spark with _SUCCESS file written for every partition?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, partition

I am doing a spark write using df.write.partitionBy("year", "month", "day")).parquet(table_url, APPEND) but this is creating a _SUCCESS file in table_url and not in each partition. I have a need to create a _SUCCESS file in each partition. Is there a way to do that?

I found a similar question -
[Writing partitioned dataset to HDFS/S3 with _SUCCESS file in each partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051103/writing-partitioned-dataset-to-hdfs-s3-with-success-file-in-each-partition)
but could not find a solution to my requirement.

Using repartition with foreachPartition seems to be an option but there iteration over each row will have to be done which want to avoid. Is there a better solution?

Comment: What would be your main goal with this? Maybe there are better ways of checking if each partition is done.

Comment: I want a file of fixed name created in each partition and if _SUCCESS file can be written in every partition by modifying the way I'm writing, it will be the cleanest way for me.

Comment: no. committers write it to the root at the end of the job, if everything else worked.

Comment: Files starting with `_` are meant to be "internal details". You should not rely-on or design-around it.