# How to write _SUCCESS files in S3 bucket's lowest level partition?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm relatively new to Pypark/Spark, so apology if I'm asking a basic question. I have looked at other StackOverflow posts (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051103/writing-partitioned-dataset-to-hdfs-s3-with-success-file-in-each-partition) and [Is there a way to do write in spark with _SUCCESS file written for every partition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602864/is-there-a-way-to-do-write-in-spark-with-success-file-written-for-every-partiti)) but they do not include workable solution.

It seems like when we use this Spark submit argument (or similar set the flag in the code) `--conf spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs=true`, Spark writes `_SUCCESS` file after it completes writing the output to S3. But the `_SUCCESS` file is only written to the base path level. For example, if I am writing to this S3 path, `s3://my-bucket/output_data/region_id=1/marketplace_id=1/` (where `region_id` and `marketplace_id` are partitions), then, Spark will write the `_SUCCESS` file to just `s3://my-bucket/output_data/`.

However, in one of the application I am working on, I need to write the `_SUCCESS` file to each `marketplace_id` partition level (the lowest partition level as I'm referring to it here) so that the next downstream job can be sure that `marketplace_id=1`'s write job is finished and start its `marketplace_id=1` processing job, and so on.

I am thinking of doing something like this:

```
# Create an empty dataframe to eventually write as a _SUCCESS file
empty_df = spark.createDataFrame([], StructType([]))

# Do some data processing/transformation
final_df = df1.join(df2, 'inner')

# Write processed data to desired partitions
s3_output_path = 's3://my-bucket/output_data/'
final_df.write.partitionBy('region_id', 'marketplace_id').mode('overwrite').parquet(s3_output_path)

# Now write _SUCCESS file in each of the above s3_output_path's lowest partition level (marketplace_id=X in this example)
# Here, I don't know how to get the list of full s3 paths (including the partitions) that final_df was written to because I need that list as a parameter to write the empty dataframe as a _SUCCESS market 
empty_df.write.format('text').mode('overwrite').save(????)
```

As I mentioned in the code snippet above, I'd like suggestions/help on

Q1: how to obtain the full S3 paths where `final_df` is written to by Spark (maybe I will have to query `final_df` to get distinct `region_id`'s and `marketplace_id`'s? If there's an easier approach, I'd like to know)

Q2: if I am doing it right or if there's a less painful way to do this

Thank you in advance for your help/answers!